# How to validate Cameroon phone number using Regex in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, validation, internationalization

I am building a mobile application in Flutter and I want to validate and check which phone number belongs to which mobile operator(MTN CM or Orange CM) when the user inputs a phone number.

Assuming that I append the country code +237, these are the general rules for a number to be valid and belongs to a particular operator in Cameroon:-

**General Rule**:

- All mobile numbers MUST begin with a digit 6.
- All mobile numbers have a length of 9 digits.
- All mobile numbers MUST NOT have any space or special character/letter.

**For MTN CM**

- An MTN number can start with 8 and take up any digit till the end  (688684749).
- An MTN number can start with 7 and take up any digit till the end  (678684749).
- Also an MTN number can start with 5 followed by a range (0 - 4) and take up any digit till the end  (651684749, 652684749, 653684749, 654684749).

**For Orange CM**

- An Orange number can start with 9 and take up any digit till the end  (698684749).
- Also an Orange number can start with 5 followed by a range (5 - 9) and take up any digit till the end  (655684749, 656684749, 657684749, 658684749).

```dart
RegExp regexMtn = RegExp(r'(^6+(?:\+?8|7|5[1-4])+[0-9]{9}$)');
```

**Attempt**
That is what I have done so far on the screenshot but it doesn't work as expected, I have gone through the regex documentation but it seems to overwhelm me.

**Expectation**
I expect to display the mobile operator's logo at the suffix of the TextFormField when it matches to the phone number and prevent the user from submitting the request if the phone number doesn't matches.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). We don't debug images.

Comment: My bad, RegExp regexMtn = RegExp(r'(^6+(?:\+?8|7|5[1-4])+[0-9]{9}$)');

Comment: I added it to the question for you, but please use the *Edit* link instead of posting a comment next time.

Comment: I suggest you clarify your question. "...or special character/letter." is vague. "special character" is not defined and it's not clear what you mean by "letter". If you mean phone numbers may contain only digits, say that. For the remainder I think it would be clearer to say, "The second digit of MTN CN numbers is 8, 7 or 5. If 5, the third digit must be 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4. The second digit of Orange CN numbers is 9 or 5. If 5 the third digit must be 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.

Comment: Phone numbers with prefix 699 are also orange numbers!

Answer (score 3):

To validate the number:

```
^              # Match at the beginning of the string
6              # something that starts with '6'
\d{8}          # and followed by 8 more digits
$              # right before the end of the string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8GUS/1).

To check if it's a MTN number:

```
^              # Match at the beginning of the string
6              # something that starts with '6'
(?:            # followed by either
  [87]\d{7}    # '8' or '7', then 7 other digits
|              # or
  5[0-4]\d{6}  # '5', any digit from 0 to 4, then 6 other digits
)              # right before
$              # the end of the string.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8GUS/2).

To check if it's an Orange number (the explanation is mostly the same):

```
^6(?:9\d{7}|5[5-9]\d{6})$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8GUS/3).

Comment: `^6(?:[87]|5[0-4]` and `^6(?:9|5[5-9])` are sufficient since you already confirmed that the number contains 9 digits. (Even `^.(?:[87]|5[0-4]` and `^.(?:9|5[5-9])` would be fine.) I concur with your advice to use three, rather than two, regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that validates an Orange and MTN number with the provided criterial.

```
/**
 * Check if a phone number is an MTN or Orange number
 * @param phoneNumber phone number to test
 * @returns 0 if MTN, 1 if Orange, and -1 otherwise.
 */
export function validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string) {
  const mtnRegexp = new RegExp(/^6(((7|8)[0-9]{7}$)|(5[0-4][0-9]{6}$))/);
  const orangeRegexp = new RegExp(/^6(((9)[0-9]{7}$)|(5[5-9][0-9]{6}$))/);
  if (mtnRegexp.test(phoneNumber)) return 0;
  else if (orangeRegexp.test(phoneNumber)) return 1;
  return -1;
}
```

When combining both regular expressions we get:

```
const regExp = new RegExp(/^6(5|7|8|9)[0-9]{7}$/);
```